# Changing font size in Visio through Visual Basic

Tags: vba, fonts, visio

I'm trying to change the font size of the text within shapes in Visio from data exported from an Excel document using Visual Basic. I need there to be different font sizes for different shapes.
Is there a Shape.FontSize = X method or something similar in VBA?
I'm new to Visual Basic so apologies if this is a rookie question.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Visio you can change properties in [ShapeSheet™](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg144579%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) environment for change font parameters

```
  Dim shp As Shape 
  Set shp = ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(4) 
  shp.Cells("Char.Size").FormulaU = "12 pt"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Do you know if there's a similar way to add bold or italics to the font?

Answer (score 0):

I find another way change font size

```
Dim shp As Shape 
Set shp = ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(1) 
With shp.Characters 
   ' set font size - 6 pt
   .CharProps(visCharacterSize) = 6 
   ' set font bold, italic and underline
   .CharProps(visCharacterStyle) = visBold + visItalic + visUnderLine 
End With
```