# VBA visio - cannot change font size in the element

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

I am wondering why I see completely no reaction when trying to change the font size of the element.

My code is:

```vb
For Each Vshp In VPage.Shapes
    If Vshp.Name Like "*UG*" Then
        Debug.Print Vshp.ID & " - " & Vshp.Master.Name
        Vshp.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "12 pt"
    End If
Next
```

Both approaches from the below links don't work either:

[How change the style of a shape-text in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272955/how-change-the-style-of-a-shape-text-in-vba)

[Changing font size in Visio through Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299242/changing-font-size-in-visio-through-visual-basic)

[image]

Comment: We dont know what is it УГ aka UG-shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [Drawing Explorer Window](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-and-creative/9781849680141/2/ch02lvl1sec05/the-drawing-explorer-window).
There you cant find page's content in tree-view
[image: ug]

In this case we can see 4 sub-shapes into UG-shape…
If you need change font size for sub-shape with text **NRTH-X-AF01AK** you need change line
`Vshp.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "12 pt"` to line `Vshp.Shapes(4).CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "12 pt"`

Answer (score 2):

Your shapes are probably groups. You need to apply your formula to the shapes within the group.

Comment: Or these shapes can have protected with [Guard function](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-client-docs/blob/main/docs/visio/guard-function.md) font size cell. In this case you need use `FormulaForceU` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.cell.formulaforceu)

Comment: When applied FormulaForceU instead of FormulaU, the result is unfortunately the same

Comment: What result you mean: no changes or get error? If **No changes** then Paul's version is accurate!

Comment: Ok if so, how could I check, that my elements are grouped? It might be a good start point for my further solutions.